# How can I filter my inbox from a@a.com OR b@b.com?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I would like to be able to filter my inbox by 2 different e-mails from "From" tag:

I tried the following and it doenst work:

```
from:"a@a.com" from:"b@b.com"
from:"a@a.com;b@b.com"
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Are you using the search box?

Comment: If you are using the search box, then your first criteria should work. Are the emails from both not shown?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, we could achieve it via **Advanced Find**(click search field>Options>Search tools>Advanced Find).

[image]

Then choose or type the senders' address in From field like below and click find now:

[image]